# how i can skip the first result of document.querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html, css

this is my html

```
<div class="modal-body">
<table style="text-align:center;" class="table table-bordered">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Line</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>aaaaaaaaa<br>bbbbbbbbbb<br>cccccccccc</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

so this commande :

```
let content = document.querySelectorAll('.modal-body');
```

show me the result like this :

```
Line
aaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbb
ccccccccc
```

i want to skip the first line : Line

and keep only this result :

```
aaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbb
ccccccccc
```

any idea ?

Comment: What is the reason that you select the whole `.modal-body` instead of the `td` within `.modal-body`

Comment: cause what i post is not the full html , if i use only td , the result is all td of html , i need only td of class="modal-body"

Comment: Yes but whats wrong with e.g. `let content = document.querySelectorAll('.modal-body td')`?

Comment: when i use '.modal-body td'   the button not work , and anyway thats not skip the first lline , check here :  https://jsbin.com/fiwixonuzo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Your jsbin does not run, on the on hand it has `<script>` tags in the javascript code (so syntax error), it is not complete, because there is no `btn-sm`, and the selector is not `.modal-body td`. So how should that jsbin show that `document.querySelectorAll('.modal-body td')` won't work?

Comment: no not work , when i add the td the button btn-sm stop working, listent i can not post the full code html and js , can you come in teamviewr 2 minut ? thats gona help me sir,

Comment: `can you come in teamviewr 2 minut ?` no. and adding a copy button, fixing the syntax error in the jsbin, and changing the selector to `.modal-body td` shows the expected result.

Comment: so i have do what you tell me :   https://jsbin.com/bivozekivu/1/edit?html,js,output    its work on https://jsbin.com   but not on my application :(    on my application when i add the td   i can not press the button copy

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to select all `<td>` elements then refer to the solution

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.modal-body tr td').forEach(f => console.log(f.innerText.split('\n')))
```

```html
<div class="modal-body">
  <table style="text-align:center;" class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Line</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>aaaaaaaaa<br>bbbbbbbbbb<br>cccccccccc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>aaaaaaaaa<br>bbbbbbbbbb<br>cccccccccc</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example shows you one of many ways to accomplish the task. It will also teach you so coding techniques.

```js
let doc, html, bod, M, I, S, Q; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
doc = document; html = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body;
M = tag=>{ // make element
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
I = id=>doc.getElementById(id); // get by id
S = (selector, within)=>{ // get first by selector
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{ // get all by selector
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
// magic under here - tiny Library above
const tdWithText = S('.modal-body>table>tbody>tr>td');
const resArray = tdWithText.innerText.split(/\n/);
console.log(resArray);
// resArray[0] is a line - resArray[1] is b line - resArray[2] is c line
}); // end load
```

```css
table{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class='modal-body'>
  <table class='table table-bordered'>
    <tbody>
      <tr><th>Line</th></tr>
      <tr><td>aaaaaaaaa<br>bbbbbbbbbb<br>cccccccccc</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```